# Allow Desktop Bridge (centennial) apps to be installed in different location

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

Trying to install a Desktop Bridge UWP app when the system is configured to store apps on another drive will cause the following error message:

> The app package type is not supported on this filesystem (0x80073d13)

Windows settings:

[image: Storage settings]

Is there a way to enable centennial apps to be installed in another location or is this a known limitation of the Desktop Bridge? It doesn't seem like support for external storage can be declared in some way (e.g. within the manifest).

Comment: What's the file system of the 'SHARE(Z:)' drive? NTFS or FAT?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSFT docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh464929(v=win.10)#frequently-asked-questions) (see last FAQ), this is **not** possible. Maybe something has changed since 2015 (*the last time the article seems to have been updated*), but your initial tests seem to confirm the docs.

Comment: Your document refers to UWP apps which actually support to be installed on a different drive (using the setting mentioned above), see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appinstaller/2016/11/23/installing-uwp-apps-to-alternate-drives/. I just does not seem to work for Desktop Bridge UWP apps.